# Track order for m4a files

Tags: music

I'm migrating some iTunes albums from my Mac to Elementary. When I add them to noise the songs are all out of order and there's no artwork. I tried Clementine to compare and that viewed the files correctly ordered and with artwork. I tried to amend the file but the edit details were all correct. Is there any way this can be fixed?

Comment: Just a follow up. Noise seems to import m4a tracks in the right order but only on list view. When I open the same album in album view the songs play out of order. It also imports the year incorrectly. Every track has a random year even though it's tagged correctly.

Comment: I am facing EXACTLY the same problem! Does anyone have a solution? The only reason I use noise is because of it's gorgeous album view.

Comment: bug? https://launchpad.net/noise

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix it! You only need to edit the informations of all your m4a songs and delete the year and the compositors!
It's a nuisance, but it worked for me... hope it helps!